# Getting SVGDocument of an SVG inside a canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I'm trying to find a way to change the fill of elements within an SVG file, that is then drawn to a canvas via JavaScript.

The only way I've managed to actually draw a .svg file to a canvas is by making an Image object, and setting its image source to the SVG file. Doing it this way however, I can't find a way to use `getSVGDocument()` on the image object.

Any suggestions?

****Added:**

This is how I change the fill of svg files via `<object>` tag, which works perfect:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('character').getSVGDocument();
var hairColor = document.getElementById('_hair').value;
var headColor = document.getElementById('_head').value;
var bodyColor = document.getElementById('_body').value;

svg.getElementById("hair").style.fill = hairColor;
svg.getElementById("head").style.fill = headColor;
svg.getElementById("body").style.fill = bodyColor;
```

Then the HTML element it's accessing looks like:

```
<object id="character" type="image/svg+xml" data="person.svg">
```

Basically I want to do the same thing, but just inside a `<canvas>` tag, so I can then move the svg around dynamically in a game setting.

Comment: An image object doesn't have an `getSVGDocument()` method, only an SVG document does.  Why don't you show us your code?

Comment: @robertc Okay I added the code I have that works, just want to achieve the same results, but within a canvas.